# Using a `Custom SQL Query` in existing Tableau dashboard to assign tasks based on row number

Tags: mysql, sql, tableau-api, rownum

I am trying to build a Tableau dashboard that assigns tasks to team members for auditing purposes. The existing Tableau dashboard pulls tasks for a date selected by the user with a filter.

Based on the results that I get each day, I would like to assign row numbers using a SQL query and assign 25 tasks to 6 members.

I have a SQL query to do that, however the date is fixed in the query and doesn't work fine when I choose a different date in the Tableau dashboard.

Download from existing table:

[image: current table layout]

Proposed table layout:
[image: new table layout]

I am looking to add a `row_num` function in the custom SQL query, and then link it to the existing table in the dashboard using a `join`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm confused by the date field having the name `resolveddate`. And confused by the goal. Are you trying to assign the 150 most recent unresolved tasks to 6 auditors, 25 each? In any case, can you just modify the original SQL query source for this dashboard, instead of writing a separate query and performing a `join` in Tableau?

Comment: Row number won’t be persistent. Do you expect the task assignments to be persistent? If so, row number is not likely a good solution.

Comment: The index() function in tableau plays a somewhat similar role as record number - not exactly the same.